# What is the difference between symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I checked that `:xyz == 'xyz'` is `false`. But we can call functions inside rails with `:index` or `'index'`. Please clear my wonder.

Comment: _"we can call the function inside rails"_ – which function?

Comment: functions inside the rails controller.

Comment: def index can be redirected using redirect_to 'index' or redirect_to :index both. so asking if both are same the reason. which cleared. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:xyz` is a symbol. A symbol is an instance of the class `Symbol`.

`"xyz`" is a string. A string is not a Symbol.

Therefore, `:xyz=='xyz'` is not true. Because the instance of `Symbol` that is `:xyz` is not equivalent to the instance of String `xyz`.

Comment: `1.0` is a `Float`, `1` is an `Integer`. An `Integer` is not a `Float`. Nevertheless `1.0 == 1` is `true`.

Answer (score 4):

`:xyz` and `'xyz'` are indeed different. That does not contradict with the fact that a method can take either type of argument. For example, `Array#*` can take a `String` or `Integer` as an argument:

```
["a", "b"] * "foo" # => "afoob"
["a", "b"] * 2 # => ["a", "b", "a", "b"]
```

but that does not mean that `"foo"` is the same as `2`.

And if you follow the logic you are implying, it would mean that all objects in Ruby are the same.

Answer (score 3):

> I checked that `:xyz == 'xyz'` is `false`. But we can call functions inside rails with `:index` or `'index'`. Please clear my wonder.

There is nothing mysterious about this.

`Symbol#==` is a method just like any other method. The person who wrote it, wrote it in such a way that it returns `false`. She could have written it to return `true` or return `42` or format your harddisk, but she decided to return `false`.

Rails methods are methods just like any other method. The person who wrote them, wrote them in such a way that accepts either `Symbol`s or `String`s. She could have written them to accept only `Symbol`s or only `String`s or to accept only `String`s on even days of the week, only `String`s on odd days of the week, and only `Integer`s during a full moon, but she decided to accept both `String`s and `Symbol`s.

The developers who write Rails and the developers who write Ruby are free to do in their methods whatever they want, just like you are free to do whatever you want in methods you write. You can write a method that accepts `String`s, you can write a method that accepts `Symbol`s, you can write a method that accepts both, you can write a method that accepts neither. It's your choice, just like it is the choice of the Rails and Ruby developers.

It implies absolutely nothing about the relationship between `Symbol`s and `String`s.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you've come across Rails' use of `HashWithIndifferentAccess`. This allows you to access a Hash using either a Symbol or a String.

In other words, `params[:a]` is the same as `params["a"]` because internally, `HashWithIndifferentAccess` converts all the keys to strings.

See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) for more information.